How the deal with the max(A) error in Sata
I use the following code to calculate maximum eigenvalue in stata
encode Name, gen(name)
spset name, coord(latitude longitude )
spset, modify  coordsys(latlong)

spmat idistance W longitude latitude,id(name) replace
spmat getmatrix W mataW
spmat eigenvalues W
spmat getmatrix W, eig(lambda)

mata:
        mataW_n = mataW/max(lambda)
end

But I got the following error:
mataW_n = mataW/max(lambda)
                minmax():  3253  nonreal found where real required
                   max():     -  function returned error
                 <istmt>:     -  function returned error
(0 lines skipped)

I have tried mata function of eigensystem() to get the eigenvalue L, and then use max(L). But it got the same error. How to deal with this problem?
Many thanks!

The lambda is a vector without plural: lambda = [5.4, 2.7, 2.4, -1.8, -1.6,1.1, -0.8, -0.8, ...]
